# How to access this.context.router (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table'
import sampleSystems from '../sample-systems';

class SystemTable extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        data: sampleSystems
    }
}

render() {
    function osName(cell, row) {
      return cell.name;
    }

    function batteryCondition(cell, row) {
      return cell.condition;
    }

    var selectRowProp = {
      mode: "checkbox", 
      bgColor: "rgb(204, 230, 255)"
    };  

    var tableOptions = {
        sizePerPage: 5,
        deleteText: "✗ Delete Selected",
        paginationSize: 3,
        clearSearch: true,
        hideSizePerPage: true,
        onRowClick: function(row) {
            const systemId = row._id;
            this.context.router.transitionTo(`/system/${systemId}`);
        }
};

    return (
        <BootstrapTable 
            className="react-bs-table"
            data={this.state.data.systems}
            striped={true}
            hover={true}
            pagination={true}
            selectRow={selectRowProp}
            deleteRow={true}
            multiColumnSearch={true}
            search={true}
            ignoreSinglePage={true}
            options={tableOptions}
            >
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="_id" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" 
            searchable={false}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="serialnumber" dataAlign="center"
            searchable={false}>Serial Number</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="model" dataAlign="center" 
            dataSort={true}>Model</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="os" dataAlign="center" dataSort={true} 
                dataFormat={osName} filterValue={osName}>OS</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField="battery" dataAlign="center" dataSort={true} 
                dataFormat={batteryCondition} filterValue={batteryCondition}>
                Battery Condition</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
    )
    }
}

SystemTable.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
}

export default SystemTable;
```

I want to be able to access this.context.router inside the render method's tableOptions variable, in the onRowClick attribute. Whenever I try to access it this way I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined`, can anyone help me fix this? Thanks!

**EDIT**

The SystemTable component is used inside the App component, is this where I should initialize the withRouter or browserHistory?

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Match exactly pattern="/" component={App} />
        <Match pattern="/system/:systemId" component={SystemInfo} />
        <Miss component={NotFound} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Are you using an ancient version of react-router? It doesn't have transitionTo anymore

Comment: This is the version of react-router I'm using: 4.0.0-alpha.3

Comment: Oh maybe I'm wrong then but I didn't think it had transitionTo anymore! So my answer should apply to you then, although it's for v3

Comment: Why his React component is not stateless? Is this lack of good design?

Comment: Yes I would say so @prosti

Comment: @DominicTobias what do you guys mean? any tips to make it better?

Comment: It is hard to say, show us your Router @Tuco and content of ```/sample-systems``` in another question.

Comment: I'm just using sample systems to test the table and make sure everything is displayed correctly, that functionality will be removed and replaced by data obtained from an api, I just set that data there for simplicity's sake while I test stuff out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `this.context` inside a `function`, which, in your case, will cause `this` to be your `tableOptions` object, instead of the component class.

There are several ways to work around this:

1) bind `this` when creating the function

```
var tableOptions = {
    /* ... */
    onRowClick: function(row) {
        const systemId = row._id;
        this.context.router.transitionTo(`/system/${systemId}`);
    }.bind(this)
};
```

2) store `this` in a variable

```
var _this = this;
var tableOptions = {
    /* ... */
    onRowClick: function(row) {
        const systemId = row._id;
        _this.context.router.transitionTo(`/system/${systemId}`);
    }
};
```

3) use ES6 arrow function

```
var tableOptions = {
    /* ... */
    onRowClick: row => {
        const systemId = row._id;
        this.context.router.transitionTo(`/system/${systemId}`);
    }
};
```

You can read more about `this` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), for example.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. I ended up using the ES6 arrow function. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to use the `context` attribute of `React` components, you must declare their type, much like prop validation. In your case, using ES6 classes, it's done like so:

```
static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

Nevertheless, consider upgrading routers as pointed out in the comments because it seems like you're using an old version. It may work fine, however some of these features are unstable and could break in the future.

Extra note: you seem to be using awesome ES6 features and syntax (way to go!) so consider not using `var` anymore and instead switch over to `let`. It's a minor detail that may save you some headache down the line.

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure to make those changes, I always appreciate any tips  for better coding. 

And I had included this in my code: `SystemTable.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
}` 

is that any different from using static?

Comment: Nope, it's the same thing :) Entirely style so whatever you like more

Answer (score 0):

To access the router at deeper levels you can use [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options)

```
withRouter(YourComponent)
```

It will then have `this.props.router`.

Alternatively you can [navigate with browser history directly](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md).

Note that components which are referenced directly in a route will already have `this.props.router`.

Note that you didn't mention what version you are using and this is for the latest.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely the way to go since, even though under the hood it's also using `context`, it'll stand the test of time since any updates will apply down the line.

Comment: How can I go about adding this inside `onRowClick: function(row) { }` ?

This is what I've tried with browserHistory: 

`import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
onRowClick: function(row) {
 const systemId = row._id;
 browserHistory.push(`/system/${systemId}`);
 }`

Comment: Nah, you can't import the browserHistory object from `react-router` whenever you want to use it because it's a new object each time. You're supposed to initialize that once in your `Router` and then work with something like `withRouter` to access the `push` method. As long as this component is a child of your `Router` then it should work.